# Mongoid has_many relationship causes Rack cookie error in Sinatra

Tags: ruby, cookies, sinatra, mongoid, rack

Writing an application using Mongoid 3.1 and Sinatra in Ruby 1.9.3. I have a model called Order that has_many Items. Whenever I try to append an Item to an Order.items, I run into problems. I have the following route, summed up slightly:

```
    order = session[:user].get_order(Time.now)
    order.items << Item.new
    order.save
    "Hi, mom!" # Garbage page so that I know nothing else is called.
```

Doing that once is okay; doing it twice causes the following error:

```
    Warning! Rack::Session::Cookie data size exceeds 4K.
    Warning! Rack::Session::Cookie failed to save session. Content dropped.
```

I've been banging my head against the wall trying to get it to stop doing this. Why is the session loading all my items? Am I not using the has_many relationship correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `User` model probably `has_many :orders`. Ruby is probably calling [`Marshal.dump`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Marshal.html#method-c-dump) to dump your user object into the cookie. You can imagine this might get huge. You should do the following:

- Only store the user_id in the session.
- Store your session server-side instead of in the cookie.

You'll need to use different middleware to store your session server-side. See [this page](http://blog.chandankumar.com/2011/06/sinatra-memcached-as-session-store.html) for an example of storing your session in memcache. Since you're already using mongo, you could use [Rack::Session::Mongo](https://github.com/migrs/rack-session-mongo).

Even though you're not using Rails, the Rails guide on session security is useful reading. [[link]](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/security.html#session-storage)

Comment: Gah, you're definitely right. As soon as I replace session[:user] with just the id, I stop getting the message. Thanks so much for helping me out.

Comment: It sounds like you're rolling your own authentication. You should take a look at [Warden](https://github.com/hassox/warden/wiki/overview), which is Rack middleware for authentication.